# jQuery 1.6 cross domain request is not working

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I'm testing a vanilla html website that requests data from a web service. My website is running locally on port 81 and the web service is running on port 61616.

This worked in jQuery 1.4.

I have since upgraded to 1.6 and seriously thinking of going back because the cross domain implementation is broken.

In IE I get resource not found and the URL shown is everything except the hostname:port, without which, the resource (of course) will not be found.

In Chrome I get the following error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:61616/ZifmiaService/Register/foo/bar/foo bar/david@company.com. Origin http://localhost:81 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

The web service has Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* set, so cross domain requests are allowed on the server side.

I also have:

$.support.cors = true;

in my client side javascript code.

I am not using jsonp and don't think I should need to with the correct settings.

What else could I be doing wrong, or should I report a bug to jQuery?

- - Added code  * *

The url becomes the 61616 url as described above.

```
this.register = function (username, password, nickName, emailAddress, callback, errorCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ZifmiaRegister.format(username, password, nickName, emailAddress),
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (zifmiaRegistrationViewModel) {
            callback(zifmiaRegistrationViewModel);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            errorCallback(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown);
        },
        beforeSend: function () { $(ajaxLoading).show(); },
        complete: function () { $(ajaxLoading).hide(); }
    });
}
```

Comment: What requirements changed in your project that upgrading to 1.6 was needed?

Comment: @david , post your ajax code, i don't think there is anything wrong with 1.6 , some settings might have got changed..post your ajax code, we can see whats wrong there.

Comment: Added code in main question. I use a string format to pull together the service URL (the service is built in WCF 4.0 Rest). You can see the previous version of the web service at: http://zifmia.textfyre.com/ZifmiaService/help

Comment: Hmm...1.4.4 gives the same response now. IT USED TO WORK!

Comment: I'm going to just avoid this since I control both the client and the service, but the point of the service is to allow any client to call the service from anywhere, including a web page.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Testing...

Comment: No one would have figured this out. It has nothing to do with cross-domain ajax. In my test data, my nickname field has often been "David C." with the period at the end. The URL gets combined to have a "./" which is breaking the call. If I make a call without that test data, it works fine.

Comment: /ZifmiaService/Register/dc44/99/david c./foo@foo.com was the problem, but I do not know why. If someone could explain and help me do some validation, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: jQuery does not support IE XDomainRequest. So you need to hook into jQuery's AJAX system or use JSONp.

Answer (score 1):

Try to append "?callback=?" to the URL where the ajax request is made. For example, "http://localhost:61616/ZifmiaService/Register/foo/bar/foo bar/david@company.com?callback=?" .

If your URL contains query strings, you should add "&callback=?".